# Collection was Modified Enumeration operation may not execute after adding Parallel.For instead of For loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, list

I have a list which contains 2 other lists and I am deciding in the loop where the items should go on the basis of type.

The `for` loop was taking 10 min so I used `Parallel.For` as I read somewhere it increases the performance. But now an exception is being thrown. Please let me know why.

**my code**

```
 var treeQuery = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query(_workitemstore, query);
            var links = treeQuery.RunLinkQuery();

            var workItemIds = links.Select(l => l.TargetId).ToArray();

            query = "SELECT * FROM WorkItems";
            var flatQuery = new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Query(_workitemstore, query, workItemIds);
            var workItemCollection = flatQuery.RunQuery();


      var workItemList = new List<WorkItemViewModel>();
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            // for (int i = 0; i < workItemCollection.Count; i++)
            Parallel.For(1, workItemCollection.Count, (i) =>
            {
                var workItem = workItemCollection[i];

                if (workItem.Type.Name == "Product Backlog Item")
                {
                    var model = new WorkItemViewModel()
                    {


                        FID = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? ((workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].LinkTypeEnd.Name.ToString() != "Child") ? workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0) : 0,

                        ID = workItem.Id,
                        Name = workItem.Title,
                        State = workItem.State,

                        priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                        //   Size =(int) workItem.Fields["Size"].Value ,
                        Size = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Effort"].Value),

                        StoryPoints = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Story Points"].Value),
                        DoneStatus = workItem.Fields["Done Status"].Value.ToString(),
                        StoryOwner = workItem.Fields["Story Owner"].Value.ToString(),
                        Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                        StoryAuthor = workItem.Fields["Story Author"].Value.ToString(),
                        IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath
                    };
                    lock (workItemList)
                    { workItemList.Add(model); }
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (workItem.Type.Name)
                    {
                        case "Task":
                            var storyid = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0;
                            if (storyid != 0)
                            {
                                var task = new TFSTask()
                                {
                                    Storyid = storyid,
                                    ID = workItem.Id,
                                    name = workItem.Title,
                                    //activity = workItem.Fields["MyCompany.Activity"].Value.ToString(),
                                    //start = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityStart"].Value,
                                    //due = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityFinish"].Value,
                                    status = workItem.State,
                                    IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath,
                                    Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),

                                    priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                                    effort = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["effort"].Value),
                                    Completed = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Completed"].Value)

                                };
                                lock (workItemList) { workItemList.Last().Tasks.Add(task); }

                            }


                            break;
                        case "Bug":
                            var bug = new TFSIssue()
                            {
                                Storyid = (workItem.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? workItem.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0,
                                ID = workItem.Id,
                                Name = workItem.Title,
                                //start = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityStart"].Value,
                                //due = (DateTime?)workItem.Fields["MyCompany.ActivityFinish"].Value,
                                State = workItem.State,
                                IterationPath = workItem.IterationPath,
                                Assignedto = workItem.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),

                                priorty = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                                effort = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["effort"].Value),
                                // Completed = Convert.ToInt32(workItem.Fields["Completed"].Value)
                            };
                            if (bug.Storyid != 0)
                            {
                                lock (workItemList) { workItemList.Last().Issues.Add(bug); }


                            }
                            break;



                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
             stopwatch.Stop();
           var k= stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  public class WorkItemViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
        public string WorkitemType { get; set; }
        public string Priorty { get; set; }
        public string IterationPath { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public List<TFSIssue> Issues { get; set; }
        public List<TFSTask> Tasks { get; set; }
        public List<Backlogitem> PBacklog { get; set;}
        public WorkItemViewModel()  // Added a public constructor
        {
            Issues = new List<TFSIssue>();
            Tasks = new List<TFSTask>();
            PBacklog = new List<Backlogitem>();
        }

    }

public class TFSIssue
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }
        public DateTime? due { get; set; }
        public string IterationPath { get; set; }
        public string Assignedto { get; set; }
        public int priorty { get; set; }
        public int effort { get; set; }
        public int Storyid { get; set; }
      //  public int Completed { get; set; }
    }


  public class TFSTask
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
      //  public string activity { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
      //  public DateTime? start { get; set; }
      //  public DateTime? due { get; set; }
        public string IterationPath { get; set; }
        public string Assignedto { get; set; }
        public int priorty { get; set; }
        public int effort { get; set; }
        public int Completed { get; set; }
        public int Storyid { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: looks like workItemList is not local to the loop, yet you are adding to it and trying to get Last().

Comment: yeah,but it was working fine before Parallel.For(was very slow) pls help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly convert any `for` loop to `Parallel.For`. Parallelization has many consequences to the code you are writing. In your case the biggest problem is probably going to be the `workItemList`, because it is being modified in the loop's body.

Before you parallelized the code there was no problem, because only one thread accessed this variable at one time. With `Parallel.For` multiple threads may access it at once which leads to problems you are seeing. `List` isn't built with parallelization support, so you have to make sure it is being modified by only one thread at one time.

The best solution would be to add locking around code that accesses the list. For example:

```
lock ( workItemList )
{
   workItemList.Add(model);
}
```

Lock on an instance makes sure, that only one thread may enter the inner critical code block at once. If another thread is already executing the block, others must wait.

Comment: don't i need to lock the workitem list when <br/> workItemList.Last().Issues.Add(bug); and  workItemList.Last().Tasks.Add(task);
?

Comment: Yes, you need to lock there as well. I just provided an example :-)

Comment: error coming sequence contains no element.(code updated)

Comment: Locking will not fix all bugs, because usage of workItemsList.Last() implies processing should be done sequenyially, not parallel. This code cannot be parallelized without modifications.

Comment: so how to make it fast ? currently it's taking 10 min in the loop @Evk

Comment: The problem is that using `Last` will throw when there are no element in the collection already. `Parallel.For` executes the loop in any order, so you can't rely on `Last`

Comment: any idea how to make the looping faster ? @MartinZikmund

Comment: How many items are there in the collection? 10 minutes sounds excessively long

Comment: 7960 items @MartinZikmund

Comment: And how are you retrieving the collection? It sounds like it is not fully in memory and data are queried during the loops execution otherwise it should not take this long...

Comment: Qquerying of `WorkItemLinks` is very slow in the TFS SDK, because each time you access them triggers another query. That is the problem that kills performance, so you can use `for` instead of `Parallel.For` again. You will need to query the `WorkItemLinks` separately into a list, then use `GroupBy` to group them by `SourceId` or `TargetId` and then access them within the loop. I am not familiar with TFS SDK, but this should be the way to go.